# Como diminuir o tamanho do input?

Tags: html, css

Alguém poderia me ajudar a diminuir o tamanho dos campos dos inputs? não manjo quase nada, provavelmente esta cheio de redundâncias, agradeço se alguém puder me mostrar o que estou fazendo de errado

```css
#reservas {
    text-align: center;
}

form{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    
}
input{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

label, input[type="submit"] {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

input, select {
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: rgb(43, 119, 103);
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 10px 2px;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: rgb(92, 170, 153);
    color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition-duration: 380ms;
}

input:focus, select:focus {
    border-bottom-color: rgb(92, 170, 153);
}
```

```html
<section id="reservas">
       
        <form>
            <label for="nome">Nome completo:</label>
            <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome completo" required target="blank_">

            <label for="tel">Telefone para contato:</label>
            <input type="number" id="tel" placeholder="Digite seu telefone" required target="blank_">

            <label for="email">E-mail para contato:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Digite seu E-mail" required target="blank_">

            <label for="dia">Reserva para o dia:</label>
            <input type="date" id="dia" required target="blank_">

            <input type="submit" value="Confirmar agendamento">
        </form>
       
    </section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Basta adicionar `margin: 0 auto;` no código CSS do seu input. Dessa forma:

```css
input{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* adição de margem automática */
}
```

Caso queira controlar o tamanho dos inputs, utilize `min-width: valor %`:

```css
input{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* adição de margem automática */
    min-width: 50%; /* valor de exemplo */
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Eai blz, um modo facil de corrigir isso é colocando todo o form dentro de uma div

```
<div class="inputs">
        <form>
            <label for="nome">Nome completo:</label>
            <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome completo" required target="blank_">
            <label for="tel">Telefone para contato:</label>
            <input type="number" id="tel" placeholder="Digite seu telefone" required target="blank_">
            <label for="email">E-mail para contato:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Digite seu E-mail" required target="blank_">
            <label for="dia">Reserva para o dia:</label>
            <input type="date" id="dia" required target="blank_">
            <input type="submit" value="Confirmar agendamento">
        </form>
    </div>
```

e no css declarar a div assim

```
    .inputs {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: isso não é a mesma coisa que o  `<section>` que já tem no código? pq o `<div>` faria diferença no lugar o `<section>`, testou esse código para ver se resolve a dúvida?

Comment: o section continua no codigo só adicionar uma div para o form